# Debugging on Android device (samsung gt15503) using eclipse

Tags: android

Hi i have a Android Samsung gt 15503. I'm trying to connect this device to eclipse. but in the ddms my device is not detected. Instead when i run my application the same emulator is launched. I can connect my handset to my computer and perform other operations like transfer of files etc.. but when i enable usb debugging on my handset then my device is not shown even in the computer. Can any one please help me on this

Comment: are you download Usb Driver package ?

Comment: yeah i have downloaded the google usb driver api 3 from android sdk manager. is there any separate usb drivers to be downloaded

Comment: do you have KIES software for samsung devices ? If you have please installed it .

Comment: do you have any url for KIES software download. Should i install it in my pc or android device?

Comment: you have to installed it in your pc . You can download it from here .http://www.soft-files.com/downloads/download-kies.html

Answer (score 1):

When you plug in the device (with usb debugging enabled) look for it to appear in the target dialogue of the run window in eclipse. Make sure it's not set to auto or it will just launch the emulator.

Comment: thanks for it Dredel, now i'm  able to stop emulator from launching automatically, but my android device is not detected yet. could you plz help me on this

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you installed kies .

After enabling usb debugging and connecting your phone should display an usb icon in notifications if not restart your phone and try connect it once again.
And also make sure all your AVD are closed.

Restarting the phone helped me to solve this issue.