# Device not detected in Eclipse when connected with USB cable

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to run my Android project on a device.

My device is not detected in Eclipse when I connect it with a USB cable.

I restarted Eclipse and I have checked that USB debugging is on, on the device.

Can anybody tell me what the problem is and how to resolve it?

Comment: Related threads [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236818/android-avd-manager-wont-detect-my-htc-hero-phone-as-virtual-device), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981498/android-sdk-not-recognizing-debug-able-device), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360105/debugging-on-android-device-samsung-gt15503-using-eclipse)..You might get more help if you explain your question better..Which device are you using?

Comment: Have you installed the dreivers for that device?

Comment: when you execute "adb devices" on your command line, can you see your device?

Comment: I have installed two driver samsung and acer samsung is detecting but acer is not detecting

Comment: I have had to modify driver files before to get them to be detectable

Comment: This answer on another question fixed it for my Nexus 4 : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16797152/375690 Change the USB computer connection to Camera (PTP)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Before starting, Make sure that **[USB DEBUGGING IS ENABLED](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=enable%20usb%20debugging)** in your phone settings !!!

1) BASIC STEP - Plug in device via USB, then go to  [device page in Android developers blog](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html). There you can find necessary information regarding adding USB vendor ids. Add your device specific ids, and restart eclipse if needed.

2)If you were able to see the device connected(using command: `'adb devices'`
) earlier, but not anymore, then  just try restarting ADB. (you can use the commands: `'adb kill-server'` followed by `'adb start-server'`. adb commands need to be executed from platform tools folder in the Android SDK, if you havent exported it).

3)If neither of them works out and you are on windows machine,
then check the installed usb drivers are correct. If not install proper drivers
Please find more information on how to install/update drivers in http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html

If this also is not working, try installing Universal ADB windows driver https://plus.google.com/103583939320326217147/posts/BQ5iYJEaaEH

4)You may also try increasing the timeout time 
Go to  preferences-> android->DDMS in eclipse, then try increasing 'ADB connection timeout(ms)' value

**Update based on newer answers:**

5)Run > Run Configurations > Target.  Please make sure, the option "Always prompt to pick device" is enabled.

**Special case: Windows 8 and Nexus 10** (from this question: [ADB No Devices Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721778/adb-no-devices-found?lq=1))

> Windows 8 wouldn't recognize my Nexus 10 device. Fixed by Setting the
>   transfer mode to Camera (PTP) through the settings dialogue on the
>   device.
>
> Settings > Storage > Menu > USB Computer connection to "Camera (PTP)"

Comment: I have installed two driver samsung and acer samsung is detecting but acer is not detecting

Comment: This may not need to be done on a Mac. This worked for me: In Eclipse, Run > Run Configurations > Target tab. Check "Always prompt to pick device" and then just pick your device in the next screen.

Comment: Step 3, on Mac "it just works" is no longer true. Now what? :)

Comment: @droid +1 on point 3, just what I needed. Well done, well done indeed

Comment: I am using Micromax Canvas2 A110 and Android Studio on Ubuntu Linux.  When I started USB debugging and USB connection to Camera PTP, it recognized the device.  If not associated with Camera, then it shows not enough permission $ ./adb devices
List of devices attached 
???????????? no permissions

Answer (score 15):

I solve this problem by updating PC portable device drivers:

Go to : `Settings` -> `Applications` -> `Development`  to enable USB debugging

1. Plug in device USB
2. Desktop "My Computer" right click -> "Manager"
3. Choose "Device Manager"
4. Portable Device
5. right click on your device -> "Update Driver software" -> Search automatically (wait about 3-5min, )
6. Done

Comment: Just in case someone searches the interwebs and finds this post. I followed the developer.android.com instructions precisely and device was still not detected. I tried S.P.'s answer and it successfully updated drivers which were originally installed from the Samsung website. Before the update finished installing Eclipse was able to see my device.

Answer (score 13):

Restarting the adb server, Eclipse, and device did the trick for me.

```
C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb kill-server

C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
```

I had the same problem as mentioned on this question.

Comment: reset of device was suffice :)

Answer (score 12):

I had similar problem, drivers was okey, but Eclipse did show me the device in Run > Run Configurations > Target tab. But I checked the option "Always prompt to pick device". And then running the application from Eclipse the prompt window finally showed my device.

Answer (score 7):

After a long and frustrating search, finally I made my Micromax Funbook p362 to connect with eclipse and made it to suit for development.

*Installed Moborobo (All in one Android smart phone management tool).
*Perform stop -server / start -server using ADB.
*Reboot the device.
*Restart the eclipse.
*Device got detected.(Eclipse - list of adb devices)

Comment: You installed moborobo in phone?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the steps provided by @asfsafgsf (above), make sure to re-**enable** your phone's developer modes/functions.  For my Motorola Atrix:

- `settings>applications>Unknown Sources`: *allow 3rd party apps*
- `settings>applications>Development`: *to enable USB debugging, mock locations, and disable phone sleep*

#### A note on developer modes

USB Debugging is the main mode you will need for running apps through eclipse when your phone is connected via usb (obviously).  Disable phone sleep is also handy for self-explanatory reasons.

Allowing 3rd party app sources allows you to beta test your app on a larger-scale.  With this, you can host your own apk and instruct your beta-testers to download it (prior to releasing it to the Google Play storefront).  More specifically, 3rd party support allows the installation of android package files that don't contain a google approved signature (required for play store hosting).  With 3rd party apps enabled, a handset will be able to run packages regardless of their source. *You should also be able to receive an APK via bluetooth and install it in this mode.*

Answer (score 2):

You can also list all currently connected devices by running the following command:

```
adb devices
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#InstallingDriver and follow the steps on the android website but on browsing for the USB folder don't use the directory specified -> ((sdk)\extras\google\usb_driver). (sdk) just means your sdk location.

Your phone should have the correct driver and it can be accessed when you plug it in and go to the CD Driver in My Computer, in my case it's G:\drivers\adb_driver. Use this directory instead and it should work. (It may be differ with devices).

Answer (score 2):

One possible reason is to check Android SDK Manager and install Google USB Driver in Extras folder if you have not installed it.

Following the steps here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/oem-usb.html#InstallingDriver allowed Eclipse to display the device.

Answer (score 2):

Do following steps to detect your device in eclipse : -

**On Mobile Side:-** For Connect USB sync, your Android device needs to have USB Debugging enabled.

To enable **Android USB Debugging Mode** do following steps :-

**Android 2.x - 3.x devices:**

Go to Settings > Application > Development > USB Debugging.

**Android 4.x devices:**

Go to Settings > Developer Options > USB Debugging.

For devices running **Android 4.2.2 or later**, you may need to unlock Developer Options before it is available within the Menu:

1. Go to Android home screen.
2. Pull down the notification bar.
3. Tap "Settings"
4. Tap "About Device"
5. Tap on the "Build Number" button about 7 times.
6. Developer Mode should now be unlocked and available in Settings >
   More > Developer Options or in Settings > Developer Options

**On PC side**

1. Connect your device to the PC with USB cable.
2. Download [Google USB Driver](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html)
3. Extract/Unzip “latest_usb_driver_windows.zip” file on your computer
   (using [7-zip free software](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html), preferably)
4. Open device manager on your PC

   - **Windows 7 & 8 users** → search for
     Device Manager from Start (or Start screen) and click to open.
   - **Windows XP users** → [Google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+open+device+manager+in+windows+xp)
5. You will see list of all devices attached to your computer in the
   device manager. Just find your  device (it’ll most probably
   be in the **Other devices** list with a **yellow exclamation** mark by the
   name of **ADB devices**), then Right-click on it and select **Update
   Driver Software**.
6. Select “Browse my computer for driver software” in the next window
7. Now click the “Browse…” button and select the “usb_driver” folder
   that we extracted in Step 3 from “latest_usb_driver_windows.zip”
   file.
8. Do NOT select the zip file, select the folder where the
   contents of the zip file are extracted. And keep the Include
   subfolders box checked
9. During the installation (as a security check) Windows may ask your
   permission to install the drivers, click “Install”
10. Once the installation is complete you’ll see a refreshed list of
    devices on the Device manager screen showing your phone’s driver
    installed successfully.

Now in eclipse do following steps to install your app in your device:-

1. Go to Run > Run Configurations > Target tab.
2. Check option "Always prompt to pick device". And then running the
   application from Eclipse,the prompt window finally showed
   your device.

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether your device is shown in the Eclipse device tab in Window > Open Perspective. If its not shown there then you need to install drivers for the the device. Once the device is visible in the Devices tab then change the launch settings for manual target. Once you launch your app then it will allow you to choose from the real device or the virtual devices

Answer (score 1):

If you have the following problem

[image]

Then you can so following to fix it

[image]

**Note : You should enable USB debugging on your android device(It will be in developer option in System settings)**

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. With my galaxy S2. So came here for advice, but couldn't find anything specific. Then I found this 'Kies' software on the Samsung site, under the section for my exact model of phone, under downloads, after clicking software. 
It installed the right USB drivers as part of the process of installing Kies and so my phone instantly then became visible on eclipse.

The Kies version for Galaxy S2 (GT I1900) = http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/model/GT-I9100LKAXEU-downloads#

There are other versions of Kies for other android models of course.

Answer (score 0):

(new) device not showing, Check List:

- Developer Option ON
- USB debugging ON
- Try changing to USB Storage/MTP/PTP
  if it installs Window driver and fails, there's your problem (verify in Windows Device Manager) fix it.

Answer (score 0):

ok this is an old thread -
but I spent nearly two days and did not get anywhere
Here is what solved my problem
I had USB debugging enabled ( finding developer options itself was a pain - I think the 7 times tap from google is childish and just plain stupid - rant over )

However HTC syn manager , eclipse ADT and windows computer management were all unable to identify my device

My problem was my phone was set to ONLY USB Charge  - this was the problem 
In 'USB Computer connection' >> Choose the option USB Storage 
Once you do this - PC will install drivers and your device will get detected by Eclipse as well as in 'Computer Management' under ''Android USB devices '

Now I still dont know a way to access ''USB Computer connection' but at that time I did get the option to change and t worked

For those ( like me earlier ) who dont know how to identify if 'Computer Management' shows their device look for 'Android USB devices '
If its present - then your device is being detected by your PC

Hope this helps some others
shankar

Answer (score 0):

On a kitkat Google Nexus 7, I tired everything here, and did not succeed. The device did previously connect properly to this computer.

Then I hit settings - developer-options - Revoke USB debugging authorisations
and confirmed that I really did want to revoke them.

I unplugged and plugged the USB. The tablet beeped and asked if wanted to authorise the computer for debugging. I said "Yes" and everything worked again.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem is with **Defective USB Cable**. I have tried those above all answers. Nothing gives me any fix. But finally i came to know the problem is because of my usb cable while changing the usb cable. While connecting through the usb cable the phone is charging but the drivers are not installed. Some usb cable don't have the option for that. So while buying check it and buy.

Answer (score 0):

Best approach is install PDA net(software) on both system as well as in android device. This software automatically installs global driver for all phones, provides easy connectivity to android device.

Follow these links to download

For system

- http://pdanet.co/

For android device

- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pdanet&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Here is my checklist in windows (not the device itself) when my device is not shown:

1. Make sure "USB debugging is turned in setting>Developer options.
2. Check status bar on your device. It tells you if your phone is connected as Media Device (MTP) or Send images (PTP). My device is only listed when PTP is selected.
3. Turn of windows firewall.
4. Turn of any proxy programs ran on whole windows ports.
5. And finally stop adb.exe from windows task manager and wait some seconds to restart automatically.