# Do LG Android phones support AVD?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

Do LG Android phones support AVD mode for development? I am unable to find an answer via Google.

Comment: hello brother do you want to add your LG device as AVD ??

Comment: @RavindMaurya: I am going to purchase LG mobile as a testing device for android thats why want to know

Comment: i want to know why are you giving my answer -1 ???

Comment: @RavindMaurya: I didnt give you -1 it might be given by other users

Comment: @RavindMaurya just guessing here but you don't try to answer his question at all.  You give him a disjointed series of instructions with no context, at all.  You don't try to explain the solution or even address the obvious misunderstanding the OP was experiencing.

Comment: @Android [Using Hardware Devices](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) or [Device not detected in Eclipse when connected with USB cable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063147/device-not-detected-in-eclipse-when-connected-with-usb-cable) may help you.

Comment: @Android just connect your phone to your system and run the commands which i gave you, You will be able to get the vendor id which you are looking for .....

Comment: I test my application in my LG Optimus 3D Max and Optimus One.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AVD (Android Virtual Device) isn't something an actual phone supports.  AVD is a way to `emulate` an Android device so that you can test your app on multiple virtual phones.

Please refer to [Managing AVDs with AVD Manager](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html) for more details.

Comment: So can I test my apps on LG Phones ?

Comment: You can create a virtual device (there are many templates meant to emulate specific LG models) matching the specs of a given LG phone and then test.  It won't be running the same Android ROM that LG phones run on, but it'll give you an idea of how your app will perform under similar condidtions (CPU, RAM, SD space, Screen Size, etc.).

Comment: @Android of course you can, see [this article](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) for details.

Comment: @MártonMolnár: ok but the main reason of asking this question is that I have an Android phone of LAVA and in Setting/Development/ I checked `USB dubugging` but then also when I am trying to find target device in Eclipse then this LAVA phone is not appearing there..

Comment: If you don't see your device in the list of targets in Eclipse, be sure you've installed the USB driver for your phone.  If not, it will not allow for an ADB connection.

Comment: @Prmths: ok Thanks trying to find driver of this phone on Google. Can you suggest me any link for the driver of `LAVA iris401e`

Comment: For what OS?  And is the OS x86 or x64?

Comment: @Prmths: Linux(Ubuntu 11.10) X86

Comment: That I can't help you with, sorry.  It seems Windows drivers aren't exactly everywhere, I have no clue with Linux.

Comment: @Prmths: its ok! Going to buy new phone in Samsung brand

Comment: @Prmths Please Don`t misguide the user....... You have also follow the procedure to attach your device to your system ....Brother

Comment: @RavindMaurya, I'm not misleading anyone but thanks for your input, just the same.

Comment: @Prmths These Commands for Linux To attach the any device as avd in android ....Thanks Brother