# Device not showing in eclipse even if USB debugging is on

Tags: android, eclipse, usb-debugging

Eclipse shows my Xperia S device but doesn't show my Xperia neo V . USB debugging is ON on my device. I have

1. Plug in device USB
2. Desktop "My Computer" right click -> "Manager"
3. Choose "Device Manager"
4. Portable Device
5. "Update Driver software"

When updating it shows drivers are up to date.

Xperia neo V ain't showing in Run->Run configuration also...

I have read [Device not detected in Eclipse when connected with USB cable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063147/device-not-detected-in-eclipse-when-connected-with-usb-cable) post but nothing works.

What can be done to solve?

Comment: Check under Settings-> Storage -> if the mode is MTP or PTP ,switch that.
Some times it can be the data cable too, which is a problem

Comment: tried restarting eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you connect you Device , notification pop up in windows saying installing device driver , click on it , It will show that "**sony sa0102 adb interface driver** -  unplugged device".
Now you need to search for it on google and then download it ..
For it's installation you need to

1. open Device manager
2. portable device then update driver software
3. browse my computer for device , select the folder location of your downloaded driver and click next.

If that doesn't work then while browsing for driver software on your computer in **device manager** there is an option which says "**Let me pick from the list of device driver from my computer**" click on it and follow process . 
Restart you eclipse and reconnect your device . That will work

There you go. Hope I helped you .

Answer (score 2):

Generally there is a driver that you will need to install on your computer, even if your driver are "up-to-date". This is common among various devices.

Try this driver:

http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/sony-ericsson-xperia-arc-xperia-neo-xperia-play-xperia-acro/

Also, make sure you are using the OEM USB cord.

Comment: Neo V is a sony ericsson model , it's driver won't be available on the link you have provided.

Comment: It seems they are on both? http://www.sonymobile.com/us/support/phones/xperia-neo-v/

Comment: Do I have to install PC companion ?

Comment: According to this link my Device build number is up to date.

Comment: @Shruti Yes, you may have to install PC Companion. Android devices are weird. Some devices work out of the box, while others need PC drivers to show up on ADB. There are certain times PC drivers that also need to be installed to view the device.

Comment: @Shruti, then check for a driver. Pretty sure that is what it is.

Comment: @Shruti just found the driver. I posted a new link on my answer.

Comment: The driver you found are for build number upto 3.x my device build number is 4.1.B.0.587

Comment: @Shruti here is another link. You can also look for these by Googling "Sony Neo V Drivers"

http://www.solvusoft.com/en/update/drivers/mobile-phone/sony/xperia/neo-v/model-numbers/