# Android application debug by mobile device in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, usb-debugging

I want to debug my android application in eclipse by my mobile(Samsung s3).
I enabled the USB Debugging option in my mobile and in the Eclipse
Android device chooser the device has been found, but its target is unknown.

Comment: Could you post a complete error message?

Comment: refer this link... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063147/device-not-detected-in-eclipse-when-connected-with-usb-cable?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem ,it was because of some simple notes this link was very useful for me.
http://www.voidynullness.net/blog/2014/05/01/how-to-debug-run-android-app-samsung-galaxy-s3-device-eclipse-windows/

regards
Ali