# Eclipse - How to add a specific driver (.ko file) as a module in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, driver

I'm runnig Eclipse Android v3.8 with Ubuntu, and I need to add a specific driver in the emulated system.
The driver is `cp210x.ko`, to connect an Arduino.
I have seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063147/device-not-detected-in-eclipse-when-connected-with-usb-cable?answertab=active#tab-top) (for USB device), but the device is not reconize yet.

I have already builded this module with this [source](https://github.com/ChrisP-Android/BananaPi-Android-4.2.2-Liab) of Android (it works in a real system), but I don't know how to add it in Eclipse.

How can I do this?

**Edit:**
I don't know if it's possible. I have try the command `lsmod` to see what driver was already runnig:

```
~$ adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
~$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
emulator-5554   device

~$ adb shell
root@generic:/ # lsmod                                                                               
/proc/modules: No such file or directory
```

So it's not the good method...

Comment: You could get the emulator kernel from the Android sources, and build enough of it that you can build modules against it, then deploy your module.  Of course it won't do anything without the hardware connected - how had you planned to accomplish that in an emulator?.  Are you running an x86 type emulator in a VM, or an arm emulator in Qemu?  In the later case, you could use a Qemu-emulated serial port in place of trying to fake the cp2102 yourself - the interface to application programs should look the same, apart from the device node name.

Comment: The emulator is called 'emulator64-arm', it's launched with Eclipse when I click on the `Run` button. I will try with Qemu, thanx

Comment: Yes, that would be Qemu based.  From looking at your other question though, this is a very roundabout way to go about rebuilding the normal android i2c accelerometer rotation scheme.

Comment: I would like to see how works this app... And maybe modify it to get the accelerator data. But i'm not dev, only a little in python. Java is another story...

Comment: It is not an "app" and java will play only a small role if any in the necessary customizations.  You have a lot of leaning to do about embedded systems, C, and Linux if you want to pursue this.