# USB cable Detection and Data transferring from Mobile to PC

Tags: android

How to detect the USB connection in android device and transfer data from android device to PC using USB cable ? Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Device not detected in Eclipse when connected with USB cable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063147/device-not-detected-in-eclipse-when-connected-with-usb-cable)

Comment: It's not possible to automatically copy files from an android device to the host computer, otherwise it would be a massive security issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This code is working which can automatically detect when usb is connected and disconnected..

 Receiver:

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Gravity;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class DetactUSB extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
    private static final String TAG = "DetactUSB";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(intent.getExtras().getBoolean("connected"))
        {
        TextView textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        textView.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
        textView.setText("USB connected..........");
        Toast toastView = new Toast(context);
        toastView.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toastView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0,0);
        toastView.setView(textView);
        toastView.show();
        }
        else{


             TextView textView = new TextView(context);
                textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
                textView.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
                textView.setText("USB not connected..........");
                Toast toastView = new Toast(context);
                toastView.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toastView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0,0);
                toastView.setView(textView);
                toastView.show();
        }



    }
    }

manifest: 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.usbdetectiondemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" >
    </uses-permission>


    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".DetactUSB" >
            <intent-filter>

                  <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE" />

            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>


And There is no need to do any thing in the activity..
```