# How to connect my phone to eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a HUAWEI G750 with android 4.2.2
I want to connect my phone to eclipse but i can't.
My USB debugging is on and my USB cable has no problem.
Is there anyway to connect my phone to eclipse and run the projects on my phone instead of the emulator?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Device not detected in Eclipse when connected with USB cable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063147/device-not-detected-in-eclipse-when-connected-with-usb-cable)

Answer (score 1):

try to instal huawei drivers from this link

http://consumer.huawei.com/en/?method=index

and then Update Driver from device menager in control panel

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the Universal USB Driver for Android devices. (f. e. http://adbdriver.com/)

Also make sure to connect your device as camera (PTP).

[image]